# Laravel app edit is showing MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
<form action="{{ route[('update'), $user->id]}}" method="post" style="border:1px solid #ccc">
{{ method_field('POST') }}
```

these are my two routes for edit and update.

```
Route::get("{id}/edit", 'HomeController@edit')->name('edit');
Route::post('update', 'HomeController@update')->name('update');
```

thi is my controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $arr = User::find($id);
        $name->name = $request->input('name');
        $email->email = $request->input('email');
        $password->password = $request->input('password');
    $arr->save();
return redirect('/');
}
```

This is my edit controller

```
public function edit($id){
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $user = User::find($user_id);
    return view("edit")->with('user');
}
```

Comment: You don't need `method_field` for normal post. It's used for patch and delete requests. Remove the method field, or use patch requests instead ( and use `method_field( 'PATCH')`

Comment: OK I see but it is still showing method not allowed.

Comment: You've problem with `route()` helper method. Check out the doc here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-route

Comment: I'd also recommend you to look into [Laravel 5.6 CRUD Tutorial Using Resource Controller](https://www.phpflow.com/php/laravel-5-6-crud-operation-using-resource-controller/). Using resources makes things a lot easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify parameters in the url route.

```
Route::post('update/{id}', 'HomeController@update')->name('update');
```

Your route is also incorrect. It should be

```
<form action="{{ route('update', [  'id' =>$user->id])}}" method="post" style="border:1px solid #ccc">
```

Also, no need to use `method_field()` for `POST` requests, they're used for `PATCH` and `DELETE` requests.

As a side note, if your goal is updating an existing record, it's recommended to use `PATCH` request. ( Just a standardised way of doing it )

Comment: I made the changes now it is showing the page can not be found.

Comment: @MamadouBellaDiallo check if `$user->id` is having the correct value

Comment: @MamadouBellaDiallo, run `php artisan route:list` in terminal and check the routes. Then take the page which you are getting page not found, check its url and try to find matching url from the `route:list` command. You can see if there's any mistakes in the url that way

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is because you do not have the csrf field in your form.
add this hidden input in your form.

```
<form action='{{ url("update/$user->id") }}' method='post'>
    <input type="hidden" 
           name="_token" 
           id="csrf-token" value="{{ Session::token() }}" />
    .
    .
    .
    <!--the rest of your form-->
    </form>
```

Comment: Now it is showing that the page could not be found.

Comment: Check your controller :).

Comment: I checked it. I set it to redirect to homepage

Answer (score 0):

```
// Edit link
<a href="{{ route('admin.tag.edit',$tag->id) }}" class="btn btn-info waves-effect">
                                                   <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                                               </a>

// blade file
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.tag.update',$tag->id) }}">
                                                @csrf
                                                @method('PUT')
                                                <div class="form-group form-float">
                                                    <div class="form-line">
                                                        <input value="{{ old('name') }}{{ $tag->name }}" name="name" type="text" class="form-control">
                                                        <label class="form-label">{{ __('Name') }}</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <br>

                                                <a href="{{ route('admin.tag.index') }}"  
                            class="btn btn-danger m-t-15 waves-effect">{{ __('BACK') }}</a>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-t-15 waves-effect">{{ __('SUBMIT') }}</button>
                                            </form>

// Route 
Route::group(['as'=>'admin.','prefix'=>'admin','namespace'=>'Admin','middleware'=>['auth','admin']], function (){
    Route::resource('tag','TagController');
});

// Controller 
  public function edit($id)
    {
        $tag = Tag::find($id);
        return view('admin.tag.edit',compact('tag'));
    }
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required'
        ]);

        $tag = Tag::find($id);
        $tag->name = $request->name;
        $tag->slug = str_slug($request->name);
        $tag->save();
        Toastr::success('Tag Successfully Updated','Success');
        return redirect()->route('admin.tag.index');
    }
```

Comment: it is showing Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::update(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected